# Unit test for createAPI redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-toolkit, ts-jest

I'm using createApi in react using redux toolkit. I've to write unit test and need to mock the 'useChangePasswordMutation' but unable to mock it and didn't get any help from other source.
How to mock the createAPI so it will not call actual API.

Here is my component code:

```
let ChangePasswordPopup: React.FC<any> = (props: any) => {
  const [changePasswordCaller,changePasswordResult] = useChangePasswordMutation<any>();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (changePasswordResult.isSuccess) {
      toast.success(formatMessage("Password_Changed_Successfully"));
      changePasswordResult.reset();
      props.modalClosed();
    }
  }, [changePasswordResult.isSuccess]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (changePasswordResult.isError)
      toast.error(formatMessage(changePasswordResult.error.message));
  }, [changePasswordResult.isError]);
  const onSubmitForm = (values: any) => {
    let submitData = {};
    if (props.isAdmin) {
      submitData = {
        UserId: props.id,
        NewPassword: base64.encode(values.NewPassword)
      }
    }
    else {
      submitData = {
        UserId: props.id,
        OldPassword: base64.encode(values.CurrentPassword),
        NewPassword: base64.encode(values.NewPassword)
      }
    }
    const data = changePasswordUrlCreator({isAdmin:props.isAdmin, data:submitData});
    changePasswordCaller(data);
  }
  const onModalClosed = () => {
    props.modalClosed();
  } 
  return (
    <ChangePasswordForm
      isAdmin={props.isAdmin}
      onSubmitForm={onSubmitForm}
      onModalClosed={onModalClosed}
      loading={changePasswordResult.isLoading} />
  );
};
```